# Searching through Active Directory in C# and authenticate with current User

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

**What i want to do:**

A user is logged into my application with his user credentials. A form has as input only a pNumber, the application should search through active directory to find the user with that number and fill out different input fields automatically (in this example only name and email).

**What i already have (C# Code, .Net 4.0):**

```
public static string[] getUser(string pNumber) {
        string[] user = new string[4];
        NetworkCredential credential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        string DomainPath = "LDAP://DC=****,DC=com";
        string strAccountId = userName;
        string strPassword = "******";
        DirectoryEntry adsEntry = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath, strAccountId, strPassword);
        DirectorySearcher adsSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(adsEntry);

        adsSearcher.Filter = "(pNumber=" + pNumber + ")";

        SearchResult adsSearchResult = adsSearcher.FindOne();

        if (adsSearchResult != null) {
            user[0] = adsSearchResult.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString();
            user[1] = adsSearchResult.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
        }

        return user;
    }
```

If i put in values for strAccountId and strPassword i know have access to AD this works fine. But this is only a workaround. I would like to authenticate to AD with the current users credentials. I can get the current username, but i think it is not possible to get the password. So i looked into other posibilitys to authenticate with DirectoryEntry [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbww641t(v=vs.110).aspx). (What i didnt really get was the DirectoryEntry(Object) Constructor)

**My Question:**

Are there alternatives i can search through AD with C# with the current user credentials?

Comment: "What i didnt realy get was the DirectoryEntry(Object) Constructor": Can you explain what you mean by this? Looks like are  heading in right direction with small set backs. Does this link help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms180885(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);

if the current user has access it will be good if not you get an exception.

Comment: Hi Alfredo, it looks like the OP is using a `DirectorySearcher` object. How does your answer help to authenticate to AD as they asked?